# How to use Alarm Manager for birthday reminder in Android? the date is read from the SQLite database

Tags: android, alarm

What to use to set alarm repeating yearly?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, MyAlarmService.class);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Main.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(2012,5,20,18,40);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setRepeating Method of Alarm Manager and

add exact one year in date which you have fetched from db

```
Calendar today_plus_year = Calendar.getInstance();  
today_plus_year.add( Calendar.YEAR, 1 );
```

After that convert it into milliseconds and pass into alarm manager setRepeat method

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what i have done in my project

```
> package com.myco.android.birthdayreminder;
> 
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.ArrayList; import
> java.util.Calendar; import java.util.Date; import java.util.List;
> 
> import android.app.ListActivity; import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent; import android.os.Bundle; import
> android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import
> android.widget.AdapterView; import
> android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; import
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.ImageView; import
> android.widget.ListView;
> 
> public class BirthdayReminderActivity extends ListActivity {
> 
>   private List<BContact> contactsList;
>      /** Called when the activity is first created. */   @Override   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> 
>     // Schedule notification
>     CheckEventsService.schedule(this);
> 
>     // TODO change presentation
>     ContactsReader reader = new ContactsReader(this);
>     try {
>       // Update list
>       contactsList = reader.upcomingEvents();
>       setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));
> 
>       ListView lv = getListView();
>       lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
> 
>       // Add it

em click handler
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
          showContactInfo(position);
        }
      });

    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Error handling
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param position
   */
  protected void showContactInfo(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactInfoActivity.class);
    BContact con = this.contactsList.get(position);
    intent.putExtra(ContactInfoActivity.DATA_KEY__CONTACT_ID, con.getLookup_Key());
    startActivity(intent);
  }

  private List<String> getContactNameArray() {
    ArrayList<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (BContact con : this.contactsList) {
      strlist.add(getDisplayMessage(con));
    }

    return strlist;
  }

  private String getDisplayMessage(BContact con) {
    String message;
    switch (con.getEventType()) {
      case BContact.BIRTHDAY_EVENT:
        // Check for valid age...
        if (con.getEvent_num_year_old() != -1) {
          message = con.getName() + " turns " + con.getEvent_num_year_old() + " " + getDayOfMonth(con);
        } else {
          message = con.getName() + "'s Birthday " + getDayOfMonth(con);
        }
        break;
      case BContact.ANNIVERSARY_EVENT:
        // Check for valid age...
        if (con.getEvent_num_year_old() != -1) {
          message = con.getName() + "'s " + getNumberText(con.getEvent_num_year_old()) + " Anniversary " + getDayOfMonth(con);
        } else {
          message = con.getName() + "'s Anniversary " + getDayOfMonth(con);
        }
        break;
      default:
        message = con.getName() + ", " + getDayOfMonth(con);
    }

    return message;
  }

  private String getNumberText(int number) {
    // Get unit digit
    int unit_digit = number % 10;

    // Add text
    if (unit_digit == 0 || unit_digit >= 4) {
      return Integer.toString(number) + "th";
    }
    if (unit_digit == 2) {
      return Integer.toString(number) + "nd";
    }
    if (unit_digit == 3) {
      return Integer.toString(number) + "rd";
    }

    // This will never hit
    return null;
  }

  public String getDayOfMonth(BContact con) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == con.getEvent_date_day() 
      && today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == con.getEvent_date_month()) {
      return "today";
    }

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-d");

    // Check for invalid year
    int year = con.getEvent_date_year();
    if (year == 0) {
      // Need a valid year here...
      year = 1900;
    } 

    return "on " + dateFormatter.format(new Date(year, con.getEvent_date_month(), con.getEvent_date_day()));
  }

  private int getEventType(int position) {
    return this.contactsList.get(position).getEventType();
  }

  class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     */
    public IconicAdapter(Context context) {
      super(context, R.layout.list_icon_text_item, R.id.label, getContactNameArray());
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      // Optimize using recycled rows - may not help since we need to regenerate display message
      View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      // Select icon image
      switch (getEventType(position)) {
        case BContact.BIRTHDAY_EVENT:
          icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_birthday);
          break;
        case BContact.ANNIVERSARY_EVENT:
          icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_anniversary);
          break;
        default:
          // TODO change to generic event icon
          icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
      }

      return row;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (cDate.equals(dbDate)) {
    Log.i("TODAY", "Dates Matched");
    Log.i("TIME MATCHED", "Currently in AM");
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    // am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, operation);

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    } 
   else {

   }
}
```

Comment: there i wants to compare time(database and current time);

Comment: and also this code is even not calling the broad cast service